# Converting One Binary Tree into another with tree rotation

Tags: algorithm, rotation, binary-tree

Given are two random binary trees. I need to find a sequence of rotations, so that tree one equals tree two after i am done with them.

### For instance:

- Tree one has 0 as root, 1 as a left and 2 as a right child
- Tree two has 1 as root, its right child is 0, zeros right child is 2
- Output: Rotate right around node 0.

How do I do that for random binary trees?

Comment: Can you perform operations on either tree?

Comment: Yes, I can. Allthough I need to return the sequence to turn tree 1 to tree 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do this for random binary trees.

For example, consider these two trees: Tree 1 has 0 as its root, 1 as 0's right child; Tree 2 has 1 as its root, 0 as 1's right child. It's obvious that we can not turn tree 1 to tree 2 by rotation.

But it's possible to do this for random binary search trees(as larger elements will be on the right of smaller elements). We can find the root of tree 2 in tree 1, and rotate it to the root. Then we just go into its left and right subtrees to solve them recursively.

#### EDIT

If it's guaranteed that the answer always exist, then we can consider them as binary search trees(as rotation will keep the properties of binary search trees). Actually, we can relabel the nodes of the two trees to change them into binary search trees, but it's not a must for solving this problem.

Now we can change Tree #1 into Tree #2 recursively using the following algorithm.

```
procedure solve(tree1: the first tree, tree2: the second tree)
    return if either tree1 or tree2 is empty
    r := root of tree2
    find r in tree1 and rotate r to the root
    solve(left subtree of the root of tree1, left subtree of the root of tree2)
    solve(right subtree of the root of tree1, right subtree of the root of tree2)
```

Comment: I cannot expect my trees to be search trees, yet i can assume that there is a sequence that will do the job. Can you go more into detail about your recursive algorithm?

Comment: In that case we can consider both of them as binary search trees and solve them recursively. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Why can I be sure that the left subtree of tree 1 after my first rotation equals the left subtree of tree2?

Comment: That's the property of binary search trees. The set of labels in the left subtree of Tree #1 will always equal to the set of labels in the left subtree of Tree #2(although the positions of the corresponding nodes may be different, that's why we need to do the same thing to the left subtree and slove this recursively) as the label in the left subtree will always be smaller than the label of the root after relabeling. It's the same for the right subtree.